# Joining two tables and set as 0 or nil if the another table id is not found

Tags: mysql, sql

How to join two tables and set it as 0 or nil according to their data type, if the other table id column is not found?

```
 Table1
| cust_id |   balance | status   |
| 1       |    50     |  active  | 
| 2       |    100    | inactive | 

 Table2
| cust_id |   limit   |
| 1       |    25     |


Expected Table after select
| cust_id |   balance |  status  |  limit |
| 1       |    50     |  active  |    25  |
| 2       |    100    | inactive |    0   |
```

`select * from table1 inner join table2 where table1.cust_id = table2.cust_id;`

I have tried this but the other entry doesn't appear.

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Left join with coalesce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` would produce matching rows only you need `OUTER JOIN` in form of `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE()` :

```
SELECT t1.cust_id, t1.balance, t1.status, COALESCE(t2.limit, 0) AS limit
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id;
```